# How to sum the numbers of multiple (undefined number) textboxes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, sum, textfield

I'm creating a table with php and html with values from a database, and the fields of the table are textfield. All the textfields from the 1st column have the same name, and all from the 2nd column have the same name... etc.

After the 5 first columns there's an empty column, where i'm supposed to show the sum of the 5 first textfields in that row. All the rows are different forms. I'm not figuring out how to do this, i don't even know if there's an easy way of choosing the textfields by forms, so any help would be great.

The sum of the 5 first textfields is supposed to appear in that empty column and the javascript function should be triggered when any textbox value is changed. If anybody as an idea of how to do this, it would be great.

If you'd like to see the table creation code:

```
<?php 
$arrayida=array(0);
$arrayidp=array(0);
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="3Ciclo"; // Database name 
 // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Cannot select Database.");


                    $queryida="SELECT * FROM areas where tipo='AE' or tipo='C'";
                    $resultida=mysql_query($queryida);
                    while($b = mysql_fetch_array($resultida))
                    {   
                        $ida=$b["ida"];
                        if (in_array ($ida , $arrayida ))
                        {

                        }else{
                                $arrayida[]=$ida;
                                /*while($b = mysql_fetch_array($resultida))
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <td> <?php echo $ida." - ".$b['nome']; ?> </td>
                                    <?php 
                                }*/

                        }
                    }



sort($arrayida);
//print_r($arrayida);
foreach ($arrayida as $key => $val) 
{   


    if($key <> 0)
    {
        if ($key == 5){
            $prev=$val;
            $queryida="SELECT * FROM areas where ida=".$val;
            $resultida=mysql_query($queryida);
            while($b = mysql_fetch_array($resultida))
            {

                $nome=$b["nome"];
                $idz=$b["ida"];
            ?> <td style="font-size:9px"> <?php echo "$nome"; ?> </td> <td style="background-color:#FFF"> </td> <?php 
            }

        }else
            {
                $queryida="SELECT * FROM areas where ida=".$val;
                $resultida=mysql_query($queryida);
                while($b = mysql_fetch_array($resultida))
                {
                    $nome=$b["nome"];
                    $idz=$b["ida"];
                ?> <td style="font-size:9px"> <?php echo "$nome"; ?> </td> <?php 
                }
            }




    }
}

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$sql="SELECT * FROM relacoes as a inner join areas as b on a.ida=b.ida where b.tipo='AE' or b.tipo='C'";
$resultrelacoes=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($resultrelacoes) + 1;

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($resultrelacoes))
{                   

                    $idp=$r["idp"];
                    $queryidp="SELECT * FROM profissoes where idp=".$idp;
                    $resultidp=mysql_query($queryidp);
                    $idacheck=$r["ida"];
                        if (in_array ($idp , $arrayidp ) )
                            {

                                    $x=array_search($idacheck, $arrayida);  
                                    $res=$x - $xpast;
                                    $a= 5-$xpast;
                                    for ($i=1;$i<=$res;$i++)
                                    {
                                        $pos=$arrayida[$xpast + $i];
                                        /*echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$pos}');</script>";*/
                                            if($i <> $res )
                                            {
                                                ?><td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos ?>" style="width:40px"  /> </td> <?php
                                            }else
                                            {
                                                ?><td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos  ?>" value="<?php echo $r["percentagem"]; ?>" style="width:40px"  /> </td> <?php
                                            }
                                            if ($i==$a){
                                                ?><td> </td> <?php
                                            }

                                    }
                            }else{

                                $arrayidp[]=$idp;
                                while($b = mysql_fetch_array($resultidp))
                                {
                                    if (array_search($idp,$arrayidp)<>1)
                                    {
                                        $a= 5-$xpast;
                                        $max = sizeof($arrayida);
                                        for ($i=1;$i<=$max - $xpast - 1;$i++)
                                        {   
                                            $pos=$arrayida[$xpast + $i];
                                                ?> <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos  ?>" style="width:40px" /> </td> <?php
                                            if($i==$a){
                                            ?> <td> </td> <?php
                                            }
                                            if($i==($max-$xpast-1)){
                                                ?> <td><input onclick="soma()" type="submit"  /></td> <?php
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?></form > </tr> <form id="1" ACTION="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
METHOD="POST"> <tr> <td style="font-size:9px;"> <?php echo $b['nome']; ?> </td> 
                                    <?php 
                                    $idacheck=$r["ida"] ;
                                    $x=array_search($idacheck, $arrayida);  
                                    for ($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++)
                                    {
                                        $pos=$i;
                                        if($i <> $x)
                                        {                                       
                                            if ($i==5){
                                                ?> <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos  ?>" style="width:40px" /> </td> <td></td><?php
                                            }else{
                                                ?> <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos  ?>" style="width:40px" /> </td> <?php
                                            }

                                        }else
                                        {
                                            ?><td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $pos  ?>" id="<?php echo $pos  ?>" value="<?php echo $r["percentagem"]; ?>" style="width:40px" />  </td> <?php

                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                        }


                    $xpast=$x;

}
$a= 5-$xpast;
$max = sizeof($arrayida);
for ($i=1;$i<=$max - $xpast - 1;$i++){

?> <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" style="width:40px" /> </td> <?php
if($i==$a){
        ?> <td> </td> <?php
}
if($i==($max-$xpast-1)){
        ?> <td><input type="submit"  /></td> <?php
} 
}

//FIM DA 1ª TABELA ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////  ?>`
```

Comment: Can you trim down your code to the relevant piece that exemplifies the problem?

Comment: there is no problem in that code, it works. i'm just no figuring out how to do that javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the gist of what you want and did not use the same stuff you used, but this will get you there if you tweak it as needed/desired:

```
 //.sumcolumn - the class of the column you want the sum to be in.
 //#tableid - id of table you have all this in

$('#tableid').on('load',function(){
    for(var i=0; i<$('tableid').find('tr').length; i++){
        var sum = parseInt($('#tableid tr').eq(i).children().eq(0).children('input').val());
        sum += parseInt($('#tableid tr').eq(i).children().eq(1).children('input').val());
        sum += parseInt($('#tableid tr').eq(i).children().eq(2).children('input').val());
        sum += parseInt($('#tableid tr').eq(i).children().eq(3).children('input').val());
        sum += parseInt($('#tableid tr').eq(i).children().eq(4).children('input').val());
        $('#tableid tr').eq(i).find('.sumcolumn').text(sum);
    }
});
```

This is sloppy, bloated, spur-of-the-moment code and there are better ways.  But this does work.  If you have jQuery.

Comment: i'll give this a try, and a closer look